# How do save the byte offset and use stream::seek or stream::position

Tags: c++-cli

I have a program which goes through line by line of an input file, displays it on the windows form, then an action button which posts the results to an output file.

I want to be able to use stream::seek, so when I close the application and come back to it it goes to the last line on the input I was on so I dont have to start at the beginning each time.

This is my current code:

```
static System::IO::StreamReader ^fileName = nullptr;   


    public: System::Void StartBtn_Click(System::Object^  sender, System::EventArgs^  e) {
count++;

if (count == 1)
{
                textBox1->Text="";
                textBox2->Text="";
                textBox3->Text="";
                textBox4->Text="";
                textBox5->Text="";
if (fileName == nullptr)

        fileName = gcnew System::IO::StreamReader (textBox6->Text);



 if (!fileName->EndOfStream)
 {
  String^ delimStr = ",";

   array<Char>^ delimiter = delimStr->ToCharArray( );
   array<String^>^ words;
   String^ str = fileName->ReadLine();


words = str->Split( delimiter );



     textBox1->Text += gcnew String (words[10]);


     textBox2->Text += gcnew String (words[21]);

     textBox3->Text += gcnew String (words[49]);

     textBox4->Text += gcnew String (words[0]);

     textBox5->Text += gcnew String (words[28]);




 }
}
 else 
 {
                textBox1->Text="";
                textBox2->Text="";
                textBox3->Text="";
                textBox4->Text="";
                textBox5->Text="";
if (fileName == nullptr)
        fileName = gcnew System::IO::StreamReader (textBox6->Text);



 if (!fileName->EndOfStream)
 {
   String^ delimStr = ",";

   array<Char>^ delimiter = delimStr->ToCharArray( );
   array<String^>^ words;
   String^ str = fileName->ReadLine();


   words = str->Split( delimiter );




     textBox1->Text += gcnew String (words[10]);


     textBox2->Text += gcnew String (words[21]);

     textBox3->Text += gcnew String (words[49]);

     textBox4->Text += gcnew String (words[0]);

     textBox5->Text += gcnew String (words[28]);



String^ fileName1 = nullptr;
                 System::String^ finaladdress = textBox1->Text; 

                 System::String^ correctString = finaladdress->Replace( "\r\n", "," );

                 System::String^ finaladdress2 = textBox2->Text;    

                 System::String^ correctString2 = finaladdress2->Replace( "\r\n", "," );

                 System::String^ finaladdress3 = textBox3->Text;    

                 System::String^ correctString3 = finaladdress3->Replace( "\r\n", "," );

                 System::String^ Action = ReqActBox->SelectedItem->ToString();

                 System::String^ warnings = textBox4->Text;
        System::String^ correctString4 = warnings->Replace( "\r\n", "," );

                 System::String^ warnings1 = textBox5->Text;
        System::String^ correctString5 = warnings1->Replace( "\r\n", "," );

                 fileName1 += "C:\\MergeData\\output.txt";
                 StreamWriter^ sw = gcnew StreamWriter(fileName1, true);


      sw->Write(gcnew String ("\r\n"));              
      sw->Write(gcnew String (words[4]));
      sw->Write(gcnew String (","));
      sw->Write(Action);
      sw->Write(gcnew String (","));

      sw->Write(correctString);
      sw->Write(gcnew String (","));
          sw->Write(correctString4);
      sw->Write(gcnew String (","));
          sw->Write(correctString2);
          sw->Write(gcnew String (","));
      sw->Write(correctString5);
      sw->Write(gcnew String (","));
          sw->Write(correctString3);

          sw->Close();


 }

   }


}


private: System::Void button1_Click(System::Object^  sender, System::EventArgs^  e) {

   System::String^ paf = textBox6->Text;
  OpenFileDialog^ sfd = gcnew OpenFileDialog();

            if( sfd->ShowDialog() == System::Windows::Forms::DialogResult::OK )
            {
                paf = sfd->FileName;
            }


    textBox6->Text = paf;
```

Comment: The Stream::Position property value is meaningless for text streams.  It will be well ahead of the line you are actually reading, StreamReader needs to read ahead to deal with variable length encoding and line-endings.  Just stop using text files, it is about the worst way to persist data.

Comment: what files should I use instead Hans?